# GridCacheStore operations are not eligible to join JTA transaction with write-behind disabled

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jta, gridgain

From testing I have found that by the time the methods in my GridCacheStore implementation are invoked by GridGain the JTA TX is already in the COMMITTING state thus changes made through my cache store (JPA operations w/ Hibernate) fail to actually commit to the database. For reference I am using GridGain 6.1.6 with Spring 4.0.5 and Hibernate 4.3.5 (JPA 2.1). TX Manager is Narayana (JBoss) 5.0.2 using JTA 1.2.

Relevant code and config at: http://pastebin.com/jzvZyi11
Relevant log at: http://pastebin.com/KCaXkAZc

Has anyone successfully used JPA with JTA for an implementation of GridCacheStore?

Comment: If you are using JPA with Hibernate, why not use GridGain Hibernate L2 Cache integration, like here: http://www.gridgain.org/platform/data-grid/hibernate-l2-cache/ or http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Hibernate+L2+Cache ?

Comment: I am not using the GridGain L2 cache because I don't think I really need it.  JPA is going to be used only for persisting historical data and some basic querying.  All of the data being used for real-time info is stored in GridGain caches. We write a lot of historical info so the L2 caches will be invalidated frequently and I don't want the extra traffic associated with maintaining those L2 caches with GridGain.  Additionally, due to a federated architecture, the JPA queries for historical data already have to be distributed over the grid as there is no central, historical database.